# Организация записи в файл

Tags: c#, логирование

Мой статический класс Logger пишет лог в текстовый файл.
Файл лога новый каждый день и на каждого пользователя.

Возможная проблема: файл будет занят, запись не пройдет.

Вопрос: Как организовать запись. Чтобы было быстро и записи не пропадали если файл был занят.

Comment: очереди и пакетная запись

Comment: У вас в файл пишут несколько логгеров? Разве ваш логгер не единоличный держатель файла? Непонятно как может возникнуть такая ситация.

Comment: Так проблема есть, или проблемы нет?

Comment: @nick_n_a У меня есть DLL в нем добавляю логи.
Ожидается режим работы, что несколько приложений будут работать с моей библиотекой. 
Обработчики исключений стоят. В таком режиме при одновременной записи в файл, один из обратившихся не запишет.

Comment: @CuprumBur библиотеки не должны писать никаких логов. Они должны кидать исключения, пользователь библиотеки сам решит нужно его писать в лог или нет.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Библиотеки используются в 1С. 
Логи нужны мне чтобы отделить действия, данные и результаты.
Бывает что 1С шлет "кривые данные", этот момент надо отследить. 
1С запускается на одной машине по много штук. И при записи логов можно что-то потерять. Мало толка будет от логов, которые теряются.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы не было проблем с занятым файлом, к нему должно быть обращение только из одного места.

Файловый поток при этом не должен постоянно открываться и закрываться, т. к. это медленные операции. Отрываем его один раз и дальше просто используем.

Чтобы запись в лог отрабатывала максимально быстро, можно поступить так: пишем не сразу в файл, а в промежуточную потокобезопасную очередь. Отдельная задача выгребает сообщения из очереди и пишет в файл (БД, посылает по сети).

```
internal static class Logger
{
    private static BlockingCollection<string> _blockingCollection;
    private static string _filename = "log.txt";
    private static Task _task;

    static Logger()
    {
        _blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_filename, true, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                streamWriter.AutoFlush = true;

                foreach (var s in _blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(s);
            }
        },
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public static void WriteLog(string action, int errorCode, string errorDiscription)
    {
        _blockingCollection.Add($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")} действие: {action}, код: {errorCode.ToString()}, описание: { errorDiscription} ");
    }

    public static void Flush()
    {
        _blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
        _task.Wait();
    }
}
```

Здесь в статическом конструкторе логгера создаётся потокобезопасная коллекция, в основе которой по умолчанию лежит очередь (что нам и нужно). Здесь же запускаем Task. Открываем файл на запись.

Метод `WriteLog` отрабатывает максимально быстро - он всего лишь кладёт сообщение в очередь.

Задача будет ожидать в цикле `foreach` на методе `GetConsumingEnumerable`: как только появляются новые данные - он будет выполняться. Выход из цикла произойдёт только после вызова метода `CompleteAdding`. Для этого предусмотрен метод `Flush`, который желательно вызвать при завершении программы. При этом блокирующая коллекция получит сигнал о завершении поступления данных. После чего закроется файл и завершится задача.

Но это не обязательно: обратите внимание на `AutoFlush = true` - это не даст потерять данные при неожиданном закрытии программы (краше кода).

Comment: Работает в **165 раз быстрее** моего кода. В лог можно писать очень быстро. 
Проблему занятого файла можно решить созданием нового.
Спасибо за понятное разъяснение кода.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать примитивы синхронизации. Например lock - она позволяет ограничить доступ к разделяемому ресурсу только одному потоку.

Пример:

```
object obj;
string filePath = "c:/text.txt";

// Здесь секция разделяемого ресурса блокируется в случае если в этот блок 
// попадает поток. Остальные потоки остаются в очереди

lock(obj)
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write) 
    { 
        // Ну а здесь код записи данных в файл
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробовал.
Создал простое приложение.
Ловлю также исключение. Лог не записан
У меня вопрос: obj  должен кем создаваться.

Comment: Как это должно помочь, если это всё в отдельном `AppDomain`?

Comment: @Андрей в таком случае нужен мьютекс

Comment: @Garrus_En мьютекс не помог


 try
{
                
                mut.WaitOne();
                using (var stream = new StreamWriter(fileName, true, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    stream.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} {инфа}");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                mut.ReleaseMutex();
               
                Console.WriteLine("Ready");
 }

Comment: @CuprumBur А нельзя логгер сделать wcf службой и отлавливать логи от клиентов?