# Многопоточная запись File.AppendAllText()

Tags: c#

Если этот метод будет выполняться в многопоточном режиме - не будет ли возникать исключение "Этот процесс занят другим процессом" ?

Выскочило 1 раз - не понял по какой причине, сам что ли открыл этот txt в момент выполнения и кликнул в него или всё таки потоки одновременно хотели записать

```
// Записи в log файл
private void ZapisiVLog(string text) 
{
    File.AppendAllText("log.txt", DateTime.Now + ": " + text + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Ну а что будет если второй поток попробует записать пока первый свою запись еще не закончил?

Comment: Этот метод открывает и закрывает файл. А это очень долгие операции. Поэтому для логирования, которое по идее выполняется часто, этот метод очень неэффективен.

Comment: 1) Запускайте метод асинхронно. 2) Сделайте блокировку на запись файла, чтобы из различных потоков не писали одновременно. 3) Если моментальная запись в файл не критична, то используйте буферизированную запись.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721410/184217) пример логгера, который можно безопасно использовать в многопоточном коде. Он быстрый. Но вовсе не является эталоном, т. к. постоянно работает дополнительный поток, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо