# правильное использование ассинхронности

Tags: c#, логирование, асинхронность, tpl, async-await

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой из методов более правильный и почему?
У меня в синхронном цикле перебирается 5000 объектов. Сначала идут вычисления, затем действия по сети и в конце запись в текстовый лог.

Мне необходимо записать в текстовый лог информацию, но чтобы это вставало в очередь TAP каждый раз в самый конец, т.к. логирование не самое важное на текущий момент.

```
    void Log(string text)
    {
        _ = File.AppendAllTextAsync($"\\logs\\{mail}", text);
    }

    void Log2(string text)
    {
        Task.Run(()=>File.AppendAllText($"\\logs\\{mail}", text));
    }

    async Task Log3(string text)
    {
        await File.AppendAllTextAsync($"\\logs\\{mail}", text);
    }
```

Благодарю заранее за любые подсказки.

Comment: Так асинхронный вызов по идее ресурсов вашей программы и не ест особо. Файл там себе пишется в фоне и пишется. Другое дело, если дёргание диска на запись логов мешает другим вашим процессам.

Comment: `но чтобы это вставало в очередь TAP каждый раз в самый конец` оно и так в самый конец встает, но это параллельная задача, например она может выполняться на разных ядрах процессора. Управление приоритетами асинхронных операций - штука сложная, и вам скорее всего не нужна. Правильное использование - `Log3`. Использовать вызов `await Log3(text)`

Comment: Вычисления у вас должны идти мультипоточно, потому что это CPU bound задача, потом асинхронная работа с сетью как IO bound и следом асинхронная запись в лог тоже IO bound. Просто делаете `await` предыщущих задач, а в конце `await` записи в лог, передав туда результаты работы предыдущих шагов, всё. Нечего тут регулировать.

Comment: В первом случае вы запускаете асинхронную операцию, но вы не узнаете когда она закончилась и как она закончилась. Второй случай - это по сути синхронный запуск с блокированием потока на пуле потоков + вы также не узнаете когда же работа сделана. В третьем случае вы запускаете и тут же асинхронно ожидаете - минус тут только в том, что вам ожидать тут не обязательно, ведь вы можете сделать так `Task Log(message) => return File.AppendAllTextAsync(...)`

Comment: Но вцелом этот ваш код смысла мало имеет, так как если вам надо логгировать, то воспользуйтесь готовыми логгерами, а если пишете свой, то позаботьтесь как минимум о буфере в памяти (чтобы жесткий диск лишний раз не напрягать) и о многопоточном доступе (если вы одновременно несколькими потоками попробуете независимо  писать в файл, ничего у вас не получится).

Comment: @tym32167 либо `=>`, либо блок кода и `return`, а у вас не компилируется.

Comment: @aepot там еще и параметр без типа, я предположил, что это несущественно, автор догадается что к чему.

Comment: То что правильный вариант №3 я уже понял, спасибо коллеги. А можно ли вызывать его не как await Log3(text), а просто _ = Log3(text)? ведь мне нет необходимости ждать окончания этой операции, а хотелось бы просто записать что-то в лог паралельно. Т.е. у меня команды: work, work, log, work, log, work,work,work, log итд. И нет необходимости ожидания логирования логирования. В моём случае правильно писать так:  _ = Log3(text)? Ну т.е. чтоб задача выполнялась асинхронно, но метод её вызывающий продолжался идти дальше. Вот это надо было в самом вопросе изначально задать. Так корректнее вопрос звучит

Comment: И да, мне нет необходимости знать чем закончится операция, т.к. я уверен, что закончится успешно. Может тогда Task.Run(Log) мне необходимо вызывать правильно?

Comment: `File.AppendAllText` - открывает файл, записывает, закрывает. Открытие и закрытие - очень медленные операции. Меж тем логирование обычно расставлено по всему коду приложения и должно отрабатывать максимально быстро. Поэтому такая реализация лога не годится для серьёзного нагруженного приложения.

Comment: Вот, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721410/184217), мой велосипед логгера. Там в начале открывается StreamWriter и используется до самого конца. Это будет работать быстро. | Не используйте код по ссылке в продакшене! Лучше взять одну из библиотек логирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async Task Log3(string text)
{
    await File.AppendAllTextAsync($"\\logs\\{mail}", text);
}
```

> А можно ли вызывать его не как `await Log3(text)`, а просто `_ = Log3(text)`?

Вызвать то конечно можно, вам нужен режим запуска "запустил и забыл", но что будет с файлом, если одновременно вы вызвали этот метод, скажем, 100 раз? Возникнет исключение при поытке открыть на запись уже открытый файл, которое просто пропадет в бездну, уронит поток, и всё, ну потому что вы его никак не обрабатываете и никак не синхронизируете доступ к файлу из разных потоков. Выглядеть это будет как в лог что-то записалось, но не всё, что вы хотели туда записать. Плохой эффект.

Что же делать - нужно использовать блокировку. Вот например [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1243358/373567) для многопоточного доступа без асинхронности.

Для вашего частного случая, можно поступить следующим образом - правильно использовать `async void`.

```cs
static readonly SemaphoreSlim _logSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

async void Log4(string text)
{
    await _logSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        // только один поток в один момент времени может попасть в эту часть кода
        await File.AppendAllTextAsync($"\\logs\\{mail}", text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ... ex.Message - ошибка при записи в лог
    }
    finally
    {
        _logSemaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Тогда можно просто вызвать

```
Log4("text");
```

И сообщение отправится в лог без ожидания окончания записи. Но как сказано выше в комментариях - лучше использовать готовые логгеры, а не изобретать свой.

**Дисклеймер**

Как вы и хотели, я сделал без ожидания, но есть побочный эффект, например идет запись в лог, и вы в этот момент закрываете прилижение. Вас устроит недозаписанный лог? Или падение приложения при закрытии? Или отсутствие последней записи в логе? Как вы дождетесь окончания записи в лог? Никак. Потому что `async void` нельзя ожидать. Рассмотрите это решение как пример и попробуйте его доработать так, чтобы ситуации, когда приложение закрылось недозаписать все логи, не возникло.

`async void` - опасно, плохо, и я не рекомендую это использовать без полного понимания, как это работает. `_ = Log3` дает тот же самый эффект, что `async void`, то есть та же проблема может возникнуть.

Куда копать - шаблон проектирования **Producer/Consumer** и подходящая вам его реализация.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.